# Having performance issue for an extract date without time to compare with sysdate,

Tags: oracle, date-format, truncate

I need to get all the rows where its 'time' field is equal to sysdate. The thing is I just want to compare dd/mm/yyyy and as my fields are in the date format I'm using

```
select *  from myTable where trunc(timefield) = trunc(sysdate)
```

If there's only one field which is truncated everything works fine, but when I want to execute that request it takes too many times (> 10 minutes and still running).

Is there a way to bypass that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an index to be used, you should remove the function from the column. You can rewrite the condition (which removes the time part from the two datetimes):

```
where trunc(timefield) = trunc(sysdate)
```

to the equivalent (where the function is applied only to `sysdate` and not the column):

```
where (timefield >= trunc(sysdate) and timefield < trunc(sysdate) + 1)
```

This way, the condition is "sargable" and an index on `timefield` can be used. With the previous condition, a table scan (or a full index scan) was required.

Comment: +1 for  'where timefield >= trunc(sysdate) and timefield < trunc(sysdate)+1'

Comment: The point is that the table is really really big so the index is ineffective for trunc function, equivalent is pretty good

Comment: The same behavior happens in PostgreSQL 10.3